# Write regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string that can have the following form

> (Class 2)  (1-4yo+) (2m5f110y)  **2mf** Good 15
>
> (Class 2)  (4yo) (2m5f110y)  **2m5½f** Standart 2 hdles
>
> (Class 2)  (2m5f110y)  **2m5f110y** Good
>
> (Class 2)  (4yo+) **3m** Good 10 hdles
>
> (Class 2)  **2m5f** Good 10
>
> (Class 2)  (4yo+) **2m5f110y** Good 10 hdles

Help make an expression that will search for meaning in bold

Comment: Where's your attempt? And in what language will you be using your regex?

Comment: Ruby: my try `/\)\s{1,3}([\dmfy\u00BD\u00BC\u00BE.]+)./m`

Comment: Not all regex is created equal

Comment: @Louis What does this mean?

Comment: He probably meant that regex are not the same in all languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
/\) (?!.*\))(\S+)/
```

[rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/PvuLrzGV8y)

Or if you don't want to have capture groups, but potentially slower:

```
/(?<=\) )(?!.*\))\S+/
```

[rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/hsF87ZgMTr)

`(?!.*\))` is a negative lookahead. If what's inside matches, then the whole match will fail. So, if `.*\)` matches, then the match fails, in other terms, it prevents a match if there's a `)` after that position in the match.

In the second regex, `(?<=\) )` is a positive lookbehind, where it ensures that there's a `)`  before the match starts.

Comment: `(?<=\) )(?!.*\))\S+` work! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3603475 You're welcome :) Feel free to mark the answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/192545).

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby 2.0, you can use this:

```
^\(Class 2\)(?: \([^)]*\))* \K\S+
```